# Disable auto hide Popover in SplitViewController in portrait mode

Tags: objective-c

In my app I am using a SplitViewContorller. In portrait mode I don't want the popover disappear when the user touch outside of it. I want keep in front till the user do something. How it's possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your [`UISplitViewControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), implement `splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:`. In that method, you should be able to set yourself as the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307) to the `UIPopoverController` that is about to be displayed. Then, you can simply return `NO` from `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:`. You will then be responsible for dismissing the UIPopoverController programatically.

Comment: Sorry Sebastian but for me is not so simple. I have Appdelegate.m, MasterViewController.m and DetailViewController.m. DetailViewController shows the MasterViewController in a popover when in portrait mode I press the "Master" button on the top. I implement the UISplitViewControllerDelegate in the DetailViewController.m using splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController: but is doesn't stop to hide the popover.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here the code that explain the Sebastian answer, just wrote it on DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController {  
pc.delegate = self; }

-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
return NO; }
```